# redux required proptypes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been bashing my head in trying to play around with this. FOr somereason my props aren't connecting in redux. Here is my error

```
VM803:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `apiData` is marked as required 
in `TestApiPage`, but its value is `undefined`.
in TestApiPage (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (created by Root)
in Provider (created by Root)
in Root
in AppContainer
VM803:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `actions` is marked as required 
in `TestApiPage`, but its value is `undefined`.
in TestApiPage (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (created by Root)
in Provider (created by Root)
in Root
in AppContainer
```

Here is my code 
TestApiPage

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/testApiActions';
import {TestApiForm} from '../components/TestApi';

export const TestApiPage = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
  return (
    <TestApiForm
    apiData={props.apiData}

/>
);
};

TestApiPage.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  apiData: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    apiData: state.apiData 
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}
    export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestApiPage);
```

testApiActions

```
export function callTestApiAction() {
return function (dispatch) {
return dispatch({
  type: types.CALL_TEST_API,
  message: "blah",

});
 };
}
```

testApiReducer

```
import {CALL_TEST_API} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';

export function testApiReducer(state = initialState.apiData, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case CALL_TEST_API:

      return objectAssign({}, state, {message: action.message});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

initialState

```
export default {

   apiData: {
        message: "You haven't called your api yet! :("
    }
};
```

When I use Redux dev tools i do see my state there and logs in the connect show it is working. not sure what's going on. Any clues?

Comment: Are you using Provider to wrap your components with store

Comment: yes i am
       <Provider store={store}>
           <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
         </Provider>

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that your initial state is the contents of `apiData`, and not an object that contains `apiData`.

In other words you set state object equal to `apiData`:

```
export function testApiReducer(state = initialState.apiData, action) {
//                                     ^ here you set state = apiData
}
```

But you want to extract `apiData` as a property of state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    apiData: state.apiData 
    //       ^ but here you expect state.apiData
  };
}
```

Change the reducer to use the entire initial state instead:

```
// here's your reducer if your state is `{ apiData }`
export function testApiReducer(state = initialState, action) {
//                                     ^ use only initialState here
  switch (action.type) {
    case CALL_TEST_API:

      // make sure you properly update the internal `apiData` part of the state
      return objectAssign({}, state, {
        apiData: Object.assign({}, state.apiData, {
          message: action.message
        });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Or change anywhere you have `state.apiData` to use just `state`.

Comment: derp good catch. made the change however i still have the same error

Comment: @PeterKarman check out my edit, your usage of Object.assign was also expecting `apiData` instead of `{ apiData }`

Comment: hrm still no luck 'export function testApiReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case CALL_TEST_API:
           return objectAssign({}, state, {
            apiData: Object.assign({}, state.apiData, {
            message: action.message
        })});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}'

Comment: Still the same exact error??? You're sure all code re-compiled/re-built everything? You should put a breakpoint (or `console.log`) everywhere you access the state and see where it breaks

Comment: yep yep. went ahead and restarted npm as well in case hmr was having issues. no errors reported from webpack or eslint

Comment: hmmm yea the only place im accessing state right now is just in the map state to props. I'm new to redux but i added the following console logs

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log('blah')
  return {
    apiData: state.apiData 
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    console.log('blah')
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}
export default connect(
    console.log('blah'),
  mapStateToProps,
  console.log('blah'),
  mapDispatchToProps,
  console.log('blah')
)(TestApiPage);

All the ones in connect fire the others no

Comment: What is `state` equal to in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: not sure if console log in mapstate and mapdispatch would fire or not

Comment: you cannot put `console.log('blah')` in between statements like that `connect(/* you cannot put logs here */)`, that changes the behavior to be invalid because that passed the result of `console.log` as arguments to `connect`.. Just log the value of `state` in `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: alright made that change and the log appears to not work in mapstatetoprops. doesn't get called i mean

Comment: I suggest [further research](https://www.google.com/search?q=mapstatetoprops+not+called&oq=mapstatetoprops+not+called&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.2703j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) then. We can't figure out much more in the comments thread here.